# responsive image gallery w/ input / label / radio

Tags: html, css, image, input, gallery

I was working on an only HTML/CSS code (no javascript intentionally) for a responsive image gallery using input, label and radio elements. I got it working like this now:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fernsehtestbild/rugcr59L/10/)

```
.tabs {margin:0; padding:0; background:none}
.tabs input[type=radio] {display:none}
.tabs label {width:25%; display:block; float:left; text-align:center; cursor:pointer; background:none; padding:0; margin:0;}
.tabs label span {display:inline-block; padding:5px}
.tabs label span img, .tab-content img {display:block; max-width:100%; height:auto;}
.tabs label:hover img {opacity:0.8}
.tab-content {display:none; width:100%; padding:5px; box-sizing:border-box; background:none; margin:0;}
.tab-content img {margin:0 auto;}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {background:none;}
#tab1:checked ~ #tab-content1, #tab2:checked ~ #tab-content2, #tab3:checked ~ #tab-content3, #tab4:checked ~ #tab-content4 {display:block;}
.tabs:after {content:''; display:table; clear:both}
```

I would like to place the four Thumbnails under the big picture but can't seem to make it work without destroying the positioning of the following elements. I want to avoid overlapping since i dont want to set a fixed height fot the image gallery, since i would like to have the opportunity to display more than one row of thumbnails while the following elements should just align after the whole gallery without overlapping.

Comment: The only thing that i can think of is that you add position:relative and top:(desire distance) to (.tabs label) css element.

Comment: That would have to force me to set a fixed height and I would have to set a position for the .tab-content (big image) aswell to align it to the top. I actually wanted to avoid this solution.